# Can any experienced matlab coders please suggest methods to improve my code eficiency?

Tags: matlab, performance, optimization

I am writing a matlab script that intends to process array data. My coding style uses absolute references to data and iterative calls to array cells. This script will process much data and I would appreciate advice on improved efficiency before I invest more time in ineficient coding.

Code as follows:

```
%{
Code to examine sparse masked thermal field data from a single layer of a
selective laser melting process
The data is provided in a .txt file such as

MaskedScaledLayer_83.txt

The data is comma separated in form - 
frame, xloc, yloc, Temp, region

1,6.273125,91.29987,255.651,7
1,5.894271,91.28776,396.2053,7
1,5.515417,91.27564,446.6481,7
2,6.273125,91.29987,472.6041,7
2,5.894271,91.28776,472.6041,7
2,5.515417,91.27564,512.7625,7
2,6.651979,90.97992,432.9355,7
...

Goal is to determine the following at each spatial location during layer:
Max Temperature
Cooling Duration
Cooling Rate
Thermal Gradients

%}

%%
% run this from the code directory
close all; clear;

% Parameters
frame_freq=300; % Hz  - camera frame rate
tolAng=10;      % deg - acceptable angle from X-Y grid
tol=0.4;        % mm - largest distance to adjacent pixel
%T_upper=500;    % degC - upper value for cool times
%T_lower=300;    % degC - lower value for cool times


% File location
pathName='C:\temp\FromJon\';
%pathName='K:\SEH\SAMME\subjects\THERM\3_Data_from_Jon\';
testData='MaskedScaledLayer_83.txt';
LayerNumber=83;


%%
% Read in data

m1=dlmread([pathName,testData],',',0,0);

frame_data=m1(:,1);
x_data=m1(:,2);
y_data=m1(:,3);
temp_data=m1(:,4);
region_data=m1(:,5);

%%
%Vizualise data locations
plot3(x_data,y_data,region_data,'.');

%%
% Determine unique x-y locations
A=m1(:,1:3);
[C,ia,ic] = unique(A(:,2:3),'rows');
numUniquePoints=length(ia);

%%
% Isolate region for fcz2, region=6
AT6=m1(region_data==6,1:4);
temp_data6=AT6(:,4);
frame_data6=AT6(:,1);

[C6,ia6,ic6] = unique(AT6(:,2:3),'rows');
numUniquePts6=length(ia6);

% Vizualise isolated data
figure
plot(C6(:,1),C6(:,2),'.')

% Store in point cloud at z=0
Z0ptCloud6=pointCloud([C6(:,1:2) zeros(numUniquePts6,1)]);

%%
%Prepare for Thermal Gradient calculations

%find nearest neighbours for each point
%indices relative to unique points
Xneg6I=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,1);
Xpos6I=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,1);
Yneg6I=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,1);
Ypos6I=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,1);
%locations and distances
Xneg6=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,4);
Xpos6=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,4);
Yneg6=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,4);
Ypos6=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,4);


for i=1:numUniquePts6
    point=Z0ptCloud6.Location(i,:);
    [indices,dists] = findNearestNeighbors(Z0ptCloud6,point,9);
    %identify direction of each neighbour
    for ind=2:5 % 1 is same point, 2:5 are candidates for nearest x/y neighbours
        if dists(ind)<tol % exclude points that aren't adjacent
            ii=indices(ind); %ii is index in Z0ptCloud6
            % at each nearby point determine direction
            pointii=Z0ptCloud6.Location(ii,:);
            u=pointii-point; %direction
            v = [1 0 0];
            Angle_Degrees = atan2d(u(2)*v(1)-u(1)*v(2),u(1)*v(1)+u(2)*v(2));
            if abs(Angle_Degrees-0)<tolAng
                Xpos6I(i,1)=ii;
                Xpos6(i,:)=[pointii(1) pointii(2) u(1) u(2)];
            elseif abs(Angle_Degrees-90)<tolAng
                Ypos6I(i,1)=ii;
                Ypos6(i,:)=[pointii(1) pointii(2) u(1) u(2)];
            elseif abs(Angle_Degrees-(-90))<tolAng
                Yneg6I(i,1)=ii;
                Yneg6(i,:)=[pointii(1) pointii(2) u(1) u(2)];
            elseif (180-abs(Angle_Degrees))<tolAng
                Xneg6I(i,1)=ii;
                Xneg6(i,:)=[pointii(1) pointii(2) u(1) u(2)];
            else
                fprintf('WARNING Points not aligned with X-Y grid');
            end
        end
    end
end

%Possible time saving:
%C/C6 is sorted for x then y so don't need to compare every location
%{
%tol=0.4;
for i=1:length(ia6)
    ThisX=C6(i,1);
    ThisY=C6(i,2);
    NextX=C6(i+1,1);
    %find next y
    if NextX==ThisX %C6(i+1,1)==C6(i,1)
        NextY=C6(i+1,2);
        if NextY-ThisY<tol

        end
    end
end
%}


%%
%find max temp at each location

temp_max=zeros(numUniquePts6,1);
frame_Tmax=zeros(numUniquePts6,1);
for i=1:numUniquePts6
    indices=ic6==i;
    [temp_max(i,1),ii]=max(temp_data6(indices,1));
    framed=frame_data6(indices,1);
    frame_Tmax(i,1)=framed(ii);
end

% vizualise max Temp
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
pcshow(Z0ptCloud6.Location,temp_max,'MarkerSize',50)
view([0 0 1]);
colorbar
title(['Maximum Temperature, Layer ',num2str(LayerNumber)]);
xlabel('X (mm)');
ylabel('Y (mm)');
subplot(1,2,2)
pcshow(Z0ptCloud6.Location,frame_Tmax,'MarkerSize',50)
view([0 0 1]);
colorbar
title(['Frame of Maximum Temperature, Layer ',num2str(LayerNumber)]);
xlabel('X (mm)');
ylabel('Y (mm)');


%%
%Find thermal gradient for each point in frame of their Tmax .

%{
for i=1:numUniquePts6
    forw_dT_dx=temp_max(i,1) ...

    %[temp_max(i,1),I_Tmax(i,1)]=max(temp_data6(ic6==i,1));
end
%}

%%
% Find Temperature History at a point
% extract multiple peaks and determine longest time between thresholds

%unique Frames
lastFrame=max(frame_data);
temp_history=239*ones(lastFrame,1);

Tmax_perim=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,1);
Tmax_perimFrame=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,1);
Tmax_fill=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,1);
Tmax_fillFrame=NaN*ones(numUniquePts6,1);
coolTime6=zeros(numUniquePts6,1);

T_upper=500;
T_lower=300;


%for i=1149 %200:200:numUniquePts6  % a few cases to test.
for i=1:numUniquePts6 % COMMENT OUT FIGURE AND PLOT
    temp_history=239*ones(lastFrame,1);
    indices=ic6==i;
    temp_history(frame_data6(indices))=temp_data6(indices);

    %longest contiguous time between thresholds
    bound_indices=temp_history>T_lower&temp_history<T_upper;
    %longest=max(accumarray(nonzeros((cumsum(~n)+1).*n),1));
    longest=max(accumarray(nonzeros((cumsum(~bound_indices)+1).*bound_indices),1));
    coolTime6(i)=longest/frame_freq;

    [pks,locs]=findpeaks(temp_history,'MinPeakDistance',50,'MinPeakHeight',400,'NPeaks',2);%,'SortStr','descend');

%{
    %figure
    findpeaks(temp_history,'MinPeakDistance',50,'MinPeakHeight',400,'NPeaks',2,'Annotate','extents');
    text(locs+.02,pks,num2str((1:numel(pks))'))
%    plot(1:lastFrame,temp_history)
    hold on
    plot(1:lastFrame,210+20*bound_indices)
    hold off
    title(['Temperature history at (x,y)=(',num2str(C6(i,1)),',',num2str(C6(i,2)),') layer ',num2str(LayerNumber),', i=',num2str(i)]);
    xlabel('Frame number');
    ylabel('Temperature (\circC)');
    %pause(1)
%}

    if isempty(pks)
        i
    elseif length(pks)==1
        %Tmax_perim(i,1)=pks(1);
        %Tmax_perimFrame(i,1)=locs(1);
        Tmax_fill(i,1)=pks(1);
        Tmax_fillFrame(i,1)=locs(1);
    else % need special cases for order and closeness of peaks
        Tmax_perim(i,1)=pks(1);
        Tmax_perimFrame(i,1)=locs(1);
        Tmax_fill(i,1)=pks(2);
        Tmax_fillFrame(i,1)=locs(2);
    end
end


figure
subplot(1,2,1)
pcshow(Z0ptCloud6.Location,coolTime6,'MarkerSize',50)
view([0 0 1]);
colorbar
title(['Cool Time (sec), Layer ',num2str(LayerNumber)]);
xlabel('X (mm)');
ylabel('Y (mm)');
subplot(1,2,2)
pcshow(Z0ptCloud6.Location,frame_Tmax,'MarkerSize',50)
view([0 0 1]);
colorbar
title(['Frame of Maximum Temperature, Layer ',num2str(LayerNumber)]);
xlabel('X (mm)');
ylabel('Y (mm)');



%%
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
pcshow([C6(:,1) C6(:,2) 83*ones(numUniquePts6,1)],Tmax_perim,'MarkerSize',50)
view([0 0 1]);
colorbar
title(['Maximum Temperature Perimeter, Layer ',num2str(LayerNumber)]);
xlabel('X (mm)');
ylabel('Y (mm)');
subplot(1,2,2)
pcshow([C6(:,1) C6(:,2) 83*ones(numUniquePts6,1)],Tmax_fill,'MarkerSize',50)
view([0 0 1]);
colorbar
title(['Maximum Temperature Fill, Layer ',num2str(LayerNumber)]);
xlabel('X (mm)');
ylabel('Y (mm)');
```

Comment: To me this seems pretty well done. Many steps are done by using vectorization. Depending on the amount of data you read from the text file this is simply a time consuming computation... How long does this script take to run? What are your goals?

Comment: profile the code `profile on; runYourCode; profile viewer` - that will show you where the code takes time -> use that to help optimise, sometimes its not where you think it is...

Comment: You're not using cells as far as I can see (those are indexed with curly braces `{}`), which is good, as those are terribly slow. Otherwise, please profile your code, and then try to address the bottlenecks. As it stands, this is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Given a better explanation, in text, of what this code does and the **only** requirement is time-wise improvement, you could try to ask this on [codereview.SE].